# I changed a setting in Photoshop and it won't launch. Can I alter settings another way?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop

I changed a setting in Adobe Photoshop 6.0 that's installed on my work's machine. I was getting a, 'Not enough RAM to open this file' error when trying to open a PSD so I changed the RAM usage setting to 100%.

Now Photoshop won't boot (gives the same 'Not enough RAM' error message) because I think it's expecting to have at least 100% of my RAM, but it'll never get that, as there's always going to be RAM in use by other applications and the operating system itself. Ten gold stars to me for that mistake.

So my question is: is there a way I can manually alter settings in Photoshop 6.0 outside of the program itself? As I do not have privilidges to install/un-install software on my machine.

Photoshop 6.0 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! I had to hit Ctrl+Alt+Shift **immediately** after clicking the Photoshop icon (not holding them and clicking like some other resources said).

Answer (score 1):

Start it while holding down Shift+Ctrl+Alt during startup.
You can find additional information [here](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photoshop-tips-tricks/reset-photoshop-preferences/)

Comment: Like I say, I had to hit that combination immediately after clicking the icon; not during.